# How can I return a column that says "No" for values missing from the result?

Tags: sql, hiveql

Sorry for the poor phrasing in the title; I can't figure out how to explain my question succinctly.

I have a list of `fruit` (`apple`, `banana`, `pear`) and want to create a table which looks like:

```
fruit   eaten

apple   yes
banana  yes
pear    no
```

from a table that looks like

```
fruit   quantity

apple   120
banana  30
```

(Note that the original table does not include pears). So far I've figured out how to get to:

```
fruit   eaten

apple   yes
banana  yes
```

by the query:

```
select
fruit,
case when quantity > 0 then "yes" else no end as eaten
from original_table
```

But I can't figure out how to get those pesky pears to be included.

Comment: In which table you have list of fruits stored ?

Comment: Check the use of `FULL LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: AS @Prdp said, "original_table" can not know, that you want pears, so you have somehow a table (or static) list of fruits you want to have included in the list.

Comment: Makes sense. So I need to make a table which has, as one of its columns, the list of all possible fruit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fruit table you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    f.fruit
    ,CASE WHEN ot.quantity > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as Eaten
FROM
    fruit f
    LEFT JOIN original_table ot
    ON f.fruit = ot.fruit
```

If you do not have a fruit table then you need to make one.  I am not too familiar with hive but this technique should work in lots of different platforms:

```
SELECT
    f.fruit
    ,CASE WHEN ot.quantity > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as Eaten
FROM
    (
       SELECT 'apple' as fruit
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'banana'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'pear'
    ) f
    LEFT JOIN original_table ot
    ON f.fruit = ot.fruit
```